# Paypal Error 550001 occured

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, live, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have used sandbox and it works fine in that, but now i go on Live and it shows me error when I tried to verify any Paypal registered id using **getVerifiedStatus**
it shows me Error **550001**(User is not allowed to perform this action) and I registered my Application on paypal by it just conditionally approved.Please give me suggestion, what should I do?

Comment: I am getting this in **Response** :


Array
(
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2015-09-13T22%3A52%3A35.826-07%3A00
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => Failure
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => 52f73b189d313
    [responseEnvelope.build] => 18018453
    [error(0).errorId] => 550001
    [error(0).domain] => PLATFORM
    [error(0).subdomain] => Application
    [error(0).severity] => Error
    [error(0).category] => Application
    [error(0).message] => User+is+not+allowed+to+perform+this+action
)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs :

- Your account is **un-verified**. So, verify your account and try again.
  If that does not help, you will need to contact customer support to get your application vetted/tiered.